# sfml crashes while drawing text

Tags: c++, gcc, sfml

I am using codeblocks with gcc compiler 5.1.0 with sfml 2.5.0.
Sfml works perfectly fine while drawing shapes but when i try to display my text the compiled program crashes.

I tried different .ttf fonts but none of them worked.

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Test");
    Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("arialbd.ttf"))
        return(-2);
    Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("raptor inc");
    text.setCharacterSize(24);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    text.setPosition(100,100);
    int i=0,j=0;
    while (win.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (win.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                win.close();
            }
        }

        win.clear();
        win.draw(text);
        win.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I did not expect any error while executing the code but the program crashed.

The program is crashing at.

```
win.draw(text);
```

Comment: Did it print an error message?

Comment: Code works fine for me. Are you sure it's loading font correctly? Just to discard, try with an absolute path to your font.

Comment: Are you linking a Debug build with the Release lib of SFML?

Comment: It did not print any error

Comment: Im using release

Comment: It might be worth running through `gdb` to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

the code is working. and i doubt it's a font loading problem, since if it were, you should get an error on this line:

```
if(!font.loadFromFile("arialbd.ttf"))
    return(-2);
```

have you tried updating SFML? even if for testing purposes, because it seems to be a bug.